# Record count using Read()

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to figure out how to get the max record count before i populate a listview grid. I'm using the Oracle 10g DB and I've tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as countNum, status, date, theTitle, theMessage, date2 " & _
       "FROM blah blah...

messagebox.show(dr(0))
```

But that makes the SQL query crash. It doesnt seem as though i am about to put anything related to "count" in my query or it will crash so is there any other way i can see how many records it returns other than that?

Thanks! :o)

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use analytical count like so:
SELECT COUNT(*) over () as countNum, status, date, theTitle, theMessage, date2 " & _
       "FROM blah blah

Comment: That worked but i cant seem to pull it from the query? **SELECT status, date, theTitle, theMessage, date2, COUNT(*) over () as countNum FROM Blah blah... MessageBox.Show(dr(4))**

Comment: What does it mean, you can't pull it out. Do you mean you can't fetch the result record?

Comment: Well, at this point I can't give you an answer. It depends a lot of what technology are you using, framework, language, etc.... You may try to post another question on this.

Answer (score 1):

When using an aggregate function such as `count` you need to use a [`group by`](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-by-sql-tutorial/) clause for all those fields in your result set that are not the result of an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote your query once in a kind of dynamic view in the WITH clause 
and combine a count and select over this query in one select.

```
WITH query AS (
 SELECT *
 FROM foobar
 WHERE foo = 1
)
SELECT
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM query ) cnt,
  status,
  date,
  theTitle,
  theMessage
FROM query
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use THIS to retrieve a simple count of records. Not sure why you would want to pull any other fields in this operation. If there are selection criteria, apply a WHERE or HAVING clause (as appropriate):

```
SELECT COUNT(YourPrimaryKey) As RecordCount
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY YourPrimaryKey
```

THen in your code use cmd.ExecuteScalar to retrieve the result . . .