# Displaying record count using VB.net and Oracle 10g DB

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, visual-studio-2010, oracle10g

I am trying to fetch my record count in my following query:

```
myCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT status, date, theTitle, 
                             theMessage, date2, COUNT(*) over () as countNum 
FROM Blah blah... 

dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
MessageBox.Show(dr(5))
```

But it just closes my program. If i comment that out then it populates just fine and doesn't close.

What could i do to correct this?

**related question [Record count using Read()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829329/record-count-using-read)**

**UPDATE: Got it working. I simply made the mistake of not putting the dr(5) AFTER the While dr.Read()**

David

Comment: Are you grouping your result by "status, date, theTitle, theMessage, date2" in the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: this question is linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829329/record-count-using-read

Comment: COUNT(*) over () is an analytical function, it does not need to be grouped in order to make a count. Just read some docs.

Comment: all data from dr(0) to dr(3) reads just fine but once it gets to the dr(4) it crashes and exits the program.

Comment: @StealthRT, what exception is being raised?

Comment: I get **Item = In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly supplied by the user.** thats all i could find about it when i put a break point on the messagebox line.

Comment: I just realized that it should be a dr(5) instead of a dr(4)... although changing that still produced the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this to hopefully get on the correct track

```
Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
    Console.WriteLine("Demo: reader ")

    ' Connect
    Dim connectStr As String = getConnection()

    Dim SQL As String
    SQL = "select STATUS , date1  , theTitle  , theMessage  , date2  , COUNT( * ) over( ) as countNum   from    (select        TO_CHAR( level, '000' ) STATUS      , sysdate date1      , level || 'aaa' theTitle      , sysdate + 1 DATE2      , level || 'bbb' theMessage      , count( * ) over( ) countRows       from        dual        connect by level < 10    )"

    Dim connection As New OracleConnection(connectStr)
    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(SQL, connection)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim reader As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            Console.WriteLine(reader(0))
            Console.WriteLine(reader(1))
            Console.WriteLine(reader(2))
            Console.WriteLine(reader(3))
            Console.WriteLine(reader(4))
            Console.WriteLine(reader(5))

        End While
    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Try

    Console.WriteLine("Done")
End Sub
```

now this works (note I had to change the reserved word "date" to "date1"

go ahead and give this a try (or at least the query) and see if it runs.  if it does run, then I would suspect that something is wrong with the query's return data

your error msg indicates that there is no 5th (or possibly 4th) element in the data reader